# Meaning of the phrase "Lease is up in four weeks"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

I want to know the meaning of the phrase

> "Lease is up in four weeks"

Thanks so much.

Comment: Have you looked up lease?  Tell us about what your research revealed and why you remain puzzled.

Comment: Yes, I did and still don't know the meaning of the whole phrase, thanks

Comment: *is up* means *ends* - the lease ends in four weeks - you will need to renew or else find a new place to live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lease is a contract you make to borrow, rent, or otherwise have temporary ownership of an item (for example a car, boat, etc) for a limited amount of time. To say your lease is up in four weeks would be to say that you only have 4 weeks until the contract will end, and you will have to return the item to the company who permanently owns the item.

Some companies may give the option to buy the item permanently, or to extend the lease for a longer amount of time. Otherwise you have to give it back.

Comment: This answer is right, but the OP might be helped to know that the word 'up' in this context means 'over' or 'done'.  That is the source of the confusion--not the definition of what a lease is.